# Not able send data to the database in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I wanna create a appointment system but its not working now. I'dont have a error actually i just have a error and it's coming from views.py (messages.warning(request,"ERROR!")). When i opened the page its coming anyway i just wanna send my informations.
**models.py**: I created models but im not sure for policlinic and doctor because it doesn't seems like charfield text. It's a option field in HTML.

```
class Randevu(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('New', 'Yeni'),
        ('True', 'Evet'),
        ('False', 'Hayır'),
    )
    policlinic=models.ForeignKey(Policlinic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor=models.ForeignKey(Doctors,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date=models.DateField(null=True)
    time=models.TimeField(null=True)
    payment= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    insurance= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    note=models.TextField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS,default='New')
    ip=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def str(self):
        return self.user.username

class AppointmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Randevu
        fields=['phone','email','date','time','payment','insurance','note']
```

**views.py**:

```
def randevu(request):
    setting=Setting.objects.get(pk=1)
    policlinic=Policlinic.objects.all()
    doctor=Doctors.objects.all()
    context={'setting':setting ,'doctor':doctor,'policlinic':policlinic}
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=AppointmentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            current_user=request.user
            data=Randevu()
            data.user_id=current_user.id
            data.phone=form.cleaned_data['phone']
            data.email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            data.date=form.cleaned_data['date']
            data.time=form.cleaned_data['time']
            data.payment=form.cleaned_data['payment']
            data.insurance=form.cleaned_data['insurance']
            data.note=form.cleaned_data['note']
            data.ip=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            data.save()
            messages.success(request,"DONE! :)")
            return render(request,'randevu.html',context)
    messages.warning(request,"ERROR!")
    return render(request,'randevu.html',context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('randevu',views.randevu,name='randevu') ]
```

**randevu.html**

```
  <!-- MAKE AN APPOINTMENT -->
  
  <section id="appointment" data-stellar-background-ratio="3">
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                   <img src="{% static 'images/appointment-image.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                   <!-- CONTACT FORM HERE -->
                    <form id="appointment-form" role="form" action="{% url 'randevu' %}" method="post">
                        <!-- SECTION TITLE -->
                        <div class="section-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                             <h2>Randevu Alın</h2>
                              {%if messages%}
                                   {%for message in messages%}
                                        <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}}"role="alert">
                                             {{message}}
                                        </div>
                                   {%endfor%}
                              {%endif%}
                        </div>
                    
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                           </div>

                             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label for="telephone">Telefon Numaranız</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                             </div>

                            
                             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                  <label for="date">Tarih</label>
                                  <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="" class="form-control">
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label for="time">Zaman</label>
                                <input type="time" name="time" id="time" value="" class="form-control">
                           </div>
                            
                             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                
                                  <label for="select">Poliklinik Seçiniz</label>
                                  
                                  <select name="policlinic" class="form-control" id="policlinic">
                                   {% for rs in policlinic %}
                                       <option>{{rs.title}}</option>
                                   {%endfor%}
                                  </select>  
                                   
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label for="select">Doktor Seçiniz</label>
                                <select name="doctor" class="form-control" id="doctor">
                                   {% for rs in doctor %}
                                     <option>{{rs.name}}</option>
                                   {%endfor%}
                                </select>
                           </div>

                           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <label for="select">Ödeme Yöntemi</label>
                            <select name="payment" class="form-control" id="payment">
                                 <option>Nakit</option>
                                 <option>Banka Kartı</option>
                                 <option>Kredi Kartı</option>
                                 <option>Diğer</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label for="select">Sigorta</label>
                                <select name="insurance" class="form-control" id="insurance">
                                     <option>SGK</option>
                                     <option>AXA Sağlık Sigortası</option>
                                     <option>Anadolu Sağlık Sigortası</option>
                                     <option>Allianz Sağlık Sigortası</option>
                                     <option>Akbank Sağlık Sigortası</option>
                                     <option>Tamamlayıcı Türkiye Sağlık Sigortası</option>
                                     <option>Diğer (Belirtiniz)</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>

                             <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                  
                                <label for="Message">Belirtmek istediğiniz herhangi bir durum</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="note" name="note" placeholder="Notunuz"></textarea>
                              {%if user.id is not None%}
                                <button type="submit" class="form-control" id="cf-submit" name="submit">Submit Button</button>
                              {%else%}
                                   Randevu oluşturmak için login olunuz!
                              {% endif %}
                             </div>
                        </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
              
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

It's my appointment page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvF5w.png)

Answer (score 1):

Because **get** method is used to render the page

and in views.py you dont write

```
if request.method=='GET':
```

As a result, the error message is executed while there is no error

add this :

```
if request.method=='GET':
```

Comment: THİS DIDN'T WORK